# facebook browser not open android version 11 in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Facebook login proper working in app but in android version 11 phone link is not open show below error..

[Screen_shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRpQS.png)

Comment: Please don't link to screenshots, add them to your post.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 5, 2021, Facebook has depreciated the support for Facebook login authentication on Android embedded browsers.

This is because of the increasing number of phishing attempts on Android embedded browsers.

The depreciation of Facebook login on embedded browsers will mitigate malicious activity.

The original post from Facebook was made on June 28, 2021.

However, Facebook delayed the depreciation to October 2021 to provide more time for developers to plan for it.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/

Please use this plugin it will be solved:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth